# How can I count the 1's digits up to 999,999 using combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is

> If you were to write out 1,2,3,4....999,999. How many times would you
> have to write the number 1? 1=1, 11=2, 1,111=4...and so on.

I know there are other ways to solve it, but I want to solve it using combinatorics and counting the number of ways to fill {XXX,XXX},{XX,XXX},...,{XX},{X} up with the digit 1.

This formula gives the correct answer but I'm not sure why.  It seems unlikely that it would be a coincidence.

$\sum_{k=0}^6 \binom6k * k \space 9^{6-k}$ $ = 600,000$

[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20binomial%286%2Ck%29%20*%20k*%209%5E%286-k%29%20from%20k%3D1%20to%206%20)

I think this might be the reason this formula works. Begin by choosing k locations in

XXX,XXX

That's $\binom6k$ such as k=2

XX{X,X}XX

Then you multiply by the number of possibilities are each X in order, $9^4$.

So, why is there a k term?

Maybe this is the number of locations in {X,X}.  Maybe the number of places to start filling with 1's.

---

Some work that seemed to be going in the correct direction. The number isn't too far off.

Treating it as a counting problem.

Again, counting the number of ways to fill XXX,XXX and then XX,XXX and X,XXX and etc.

Add

$\sum \binom6k * 9^{(6-k)}$ where k=1,...,6

$\sum \binom5k * 9^{(5-k)}$ where k=1,...5

$\sum \binom4k * 9^{(4-k)}$

$\sum \binom3k * 9^{(3-k)}$

$\sum \binom2k * 9^{(2-k)}$

$\sum \binom1k * 9^{(1-k)}$

=513240

[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%206%20%20binomial%286%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%286-k%29%5D%20%2B%20%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%205%20binomial%285%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%285-k%29%5D%20%2B%20%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%204%20%20binomial%284%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%284-k%29%5D%20%20)

[wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%203%20binomial%283%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%283-k%29%5D%2B%20%20%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%202%20binomial%282%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%282-k%29%5D%20%2B%20%5Bsum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%201%20binomial%281%2Ck%29%20*%209%5E%281-k%29%5D%20%20)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The $k$ term is there because you need to write the number $1$ $k$ - times. In your effort, be careful because for example $123$ can be written as $000123$ so don’t bother with less than $6$ digits

Comment: In this problem, it is both harmless and advantageous to zero-fill (on the left) each number, so that each number has exactly $6$ digits.  The reason that it is harmless is that you are counting the occurrences of some digit other than $0$.  The reason that it is advantageous is that it facilitates the $\displaystyle \binom{6}{k}$ type of analysis.

Comment: As an aside... arranging the numbers one 6-digit number per row... you are effectively counting the occurrences of $1$'s left to right, then grouping, then adding top-to-bottom.  It can be helpful to instead add top-to-bottom, treating the ones-place, tens-place, hundreds-place etc... separately.  Include zero in our list of numbers as well.  In doing so, you should see that exactly a tenth of the numbers have a $1$ in the hundred-thousandths place, a tenth have a $1$ in the ten-thousandths place, etc... for a total of $100000\cdot 6=600000$ occurrences of $1$ written.

Comment: As for your second attempt, that is wrong.  First, you aren't scaling the result by the number of $1$'s you had found in each number... you should be multiplying by $k$.  Second, you have overlap since you are with the $9$ in your calculations implying that you are allowing zero as a digit and so you counted the "four digit number" $0123$ in your third summation as well as counting the "five digit number" $00123$ in your second summation... but these are in reality the same number.  If you wanted to continue with this approach, don't allow leading zeroes and scale the results.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Could you please consider writing your comment as an answer because it is correct and it is actually answering my exact question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we give a *combinatorial* approach in order to answer OPs question. We consider  all $10^6$ words of length $6$ which are built from digits $0,1,\ldots,9$. We are looking for the number of occurrences of $1$ in these words. We represent each word as function
\begin{align*}
f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to\{0,1,\ldots,9\}
\end{align*}
where the $j$-th position, $1\leq j\leq 6$ of a word is mapped to a digit from $0$ to $9$. We denote with $X$ the set of *all* these functions:
\begin{align*}
X=\{f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to\{0,1,\ldots,9\}\}
\end{align*}

**Combinatorial approach:**

- We partition the set of words according to the number of $1$'s they contain. In terms of functions in $X$ we partition $X$ by defining sets $A_k$ with
  \begin{align*}
  A_k=\{f\in X:\left|f^{-1}(1)\right|=k\}\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq 6
  \end{align*}
  containing functions in $X$ which map precisely $0\leq k\leq 6$ positions from $1,\dots,6$ to the digit $1$. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  X&=\dot{\bigcup_{0\leq k\leq 6}} A_k\\
  |X|&=\sum_{k=0}^6 \left|A_k\right|=\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{6}{k}9^{6-k}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

  The summands of the right-hand side of (1) are $\binom{6}{k}9^{6-k}$ since we have $\binom{6}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ $1$'s from $6$ positions leaving $9^{6-k}$ ways to place $0,2,3,\ldots,9$ to the remaining $6-k$ positions.

  Since each function in $A_k$ maps $k$ positions to $1$ we have to take each of them with multiplicity $k$ in order to count the number of $1$s. We so obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^6 k|A_k|=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{6}{k}k9^{6-k}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

- Another way to count the number of $1$ in these words is to consider functions $B_j\subset X$ which map the $j$-th position of a word ($1\leq j\leq 6$) to $1$. We get
  \begin{align*}
  B_j=\{f\in X: j\in f^{-1}(1)\}\qquad\qquad 1\leq j\leq 6
  \end{align*}
  We have $|B_j|=10^5$ since besides the $j$-th position which is mapped to $1$, the other $5$ positions can be mapped to  any value from $0,1,\ldots, 9$. Summing up the cardinalities of $B_j, 1\leq j\leq 6$, we get
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{j=1}^6 |B_j|=6\cdot 10^5\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
  Note, the $B_j$ do not partition the set $X$, since positions other than $j$ may also be mapped to $1$.

> But since we count each of the functions in $B_j$ just once, we obtain from (2) and (3) the identity
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{6}{k}k9^{6-k}=6\cdot 10^5}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> We can verify identity (4) *algebraically* via
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^6}\color{blue}{\binom{6}{k}k9^{6-k}}
> &=6\sum_{k=1}^6\binom{5}{k-1}9^{6-k}\tag{5.1}\\
> &=6\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}9^{5-k}\tag{5.2}\\
> &=6(9+1)^5\tag{5.3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=6\cdot 10^5}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (5.1) we skip in the right-hand sum the summand with $k=0$ which does not contribute. We also use the binomial identity $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
- In (5.2) we shift the index and start with $k=0$.
- In (5.3) we apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Because it doesn't make an impact, let's try to count the number of times $1$ appears in the numbers from $0$ to $999999$.

We can create all $10^6$ numbers by considering all possible ways to assign a digit ($0$ to $9$) to each of the places in $XXXXXX$.

Since $1$ appears in each place $\frac{1}{10}$ of the time, we have that $1$ appears in the $k^\text{th}$ place exactly $\frac{10^6}{10}=10^5$ times.

Since there are $6$ places, we have that $1$ appears $\boxed{6\cdot 10^5}$ times in total.

**P.S.** There is also a nice sum identity that will help you in your approach
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} kb^{n-k}=n(1+b)^{n-1}$$
You can substitute $n=6$ and $b=9$ to get your expression. To prove this, consider the binomial theorem, which states that
$$f(a,b)=(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n-k}$$
Take the partial derivative wrt to $a$ to get
$$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=n(a+b)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k a^{k-1} b^{n-k}$$
Now plug in $a=1$ to get
$$n(1+b)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k b^{n-k}$$

Comment: By this logic, you're saying that $1$ appears in $11 \cdot 10^{10}$ numbers out of $10 ^ {11}$? That is utterly absurd.

Comment: No I'm saying that $1$ appears $11\cdot 10^{10}$ times in the digits of the first $10^{11}$ natural numbers. There is difference in what you are saying and what the problem is asking.

Comment: In that case the problem is one of simple uniform distribution, no need for the complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you find complex about my solution. It is only $4$ lines.

Comment: Stating that the distribution of the digits is a uniform one is far more concise and useful, as well as highlighting the salient property at play.

Answer (score 2):

Write out every number from $0$ to $999,999$, using exactly six digits for each number, with leading zeroes if necessary.

Then one in every ten digits is a $1$, by symmetry; and there are 6,000,000 digits in total.

So there are 600,000 $1$'s.

Comment: "I know there are other ways to solve it, but I want to solve it using combinatorics and counting the number of ways to fill {XXX,XXX},{XX,XXX},...,{XX},{X} up with the digit 1."  This doesn't use the approach the OP specifically wanted.  (Although I admit this is the obvious and easiest approach and the OP's approach is a complex [but valid].)

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Piece by piece:

$\sum_{k=0}^6$.  $k$ represents the numbers of times the digit $1$ appears in numbers where it occurs $0$ times.  Then we count how many times the number of the digit $1$ appears in numbers where it occurs $1$ time.  THen how many times the number occurs in numbers where it occurs $2$ times.  etc.

${6 \choose k}$.   If the digit $1$ occurs $k$ times in a number there are ${6\choose k}$ ways to choose the positions in which the digit $1 can occur.

$9^{6-k}$.  So given that there we have $k$ $1$s arranged in particular positions what are the options for digits in the remaining positions? Well, there are $9$ chooses of digits (anything *but* $1$) and there and $6-k$ remaining positions.  So there are $9^{6-k}$ ways we can fill in the remaining positions.

And thus:

${6\choose k}9^{6-k}$.  This is the number of numbers that have $k$ ones.  There are ${6\choose k}$ ways to fill in $k$ ones into $6$ slots and there are $9^{6-k}$ ways to fill in the remaining slots so there are ${6\choose k}9^{6-k}$ numbers total that have $k$ ones in them.

$\color{orange}{6\choose k}k\color{orange}{9^{6-k}}$.  And how many ones *are* there in a number that has $k$ ones.  Well... $k$ of course.  That's what we actually count.  ... And that's it.

=======  THE END =========

====== EPILOGUE======

Maybe to get a feel be trying it:

1. How many times do $1$ appear in numbers where one occurs $0$ times:

Well there ${6\choose 0} = 1$ ways to position the $0$ ones.  Namely $XXXXXX$.  And there are $6-0=6$ of these $X$ non-one positions.  We can fill each of these with $9$ possible digits so there are $9^{6}$ such numbers.  They are $000000, 000002, 000003,....000009, 000020, 000022, ..... ,999998, 999999$.

And how many times does the digit one appear in these $9^6$ such numbers.  Well, each number has $0$ ones so in total there are ... $9^6 \cdot 0=0$ of them.  (Duh....)

2. How many times do $1$ appear in numbers where one occurs $1$ times:

Well, there are ${6\choose 1} = 6$ ways to position the $1$ one. Namely $1XXXXX, X1XXXX, XX1XXX,XXX1XX,XXXX1X,XXXXX1$.  And how many ways to fill in the $6-1=5$ $X$ positions?  Well, $9^5$.  So there are $6\times 9^5$ such numbers.  (From $000001,000021, 000031,.....,000091,000201,.....,999981,999991, 000010,000012,....., 199998,199999$... the was no reason to least them by size order... this way they are listed by position of the $1$ first, and size order of the remaining positions).

And how many times does the digit $1$ occur in these $6\cdot 9^5$ such numbers? Well, it occurs exactly once in each number so $1\times 6\cdot 9^5 = 6\cdot 9^5$ times.

3. How many times do $1$ appear in numbers where one occurs $2$ times:

Well, there are ${6\choose 2} = 15$ ways to position the $1$ one. Namely $11XXX, 1X1XXX, ....., XXX11X, XXX1X1,XXXX11$.  And how many ways to fill in the $6-2=4$ $X$ positions?  Well, $9^4$.  So there are $15\times 9^4$ such numbers.

And how many times does the digit $1$ occur in these $15\cdot 9^4$ such numbers? Well, it occurs exactly $2$ timse in each number so $2\times 15\cdot 9^4$ times.

And so on....

===== NEXT ON YOUR READING LIST ==========

This is, of course, a pretty inefficient way to count them.

***FAR*** easier to count there are $10^5$ numbers where $1$ occurs in the first position (and there are $10^5$ chooses for the remaining $5$ positions) so that accounts for $10^5$ occurrences of the digit $1$.  Do that for each position and there are $6\times 10^5$ occurrences of the digit $1$ in any position.